# How to find out the order of integration of a combination of iid random series?

Tags: self-learning, time-series, order-of-integration

$\varepsilon_{1j}, \varepsilon_{2j}, \varepsilon_{3j}  ∼ iid(0; 1)$ and they are three independent processes.

$ y_{t} =x\sum_{i=1}^{t}\sum_{j=1}^{i} \varepsilon_{1j} + y\sum_{i=1}^{t} \varepsilon_{2i} +  \varepsilon_{3t}$

$x$, $y$ are non-zero constants.

How to find the order of integration $ y_{t} $?

I think it is $I(2)$. But I am not sure how to prove it. Would "constant mean and variance" for all $t$ enough to prove that the difference are stationary? If not, how to prove that the autocovariance is constant for all $t$?

Are there better ways to prove that e.g. the second difference of $ y_{t} $ is stationary?

Comment: An answer is provided here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/343028/how-to-find-out-the-order-of-integration-of-a-combination-of-iid-random-series